# get second to last comment php woo commerce followup email

Tags: php, woocommerce

I found this handy code to add order notes to the completed email. I really just want to add the last two notes if possible. Can someone tell me what I would need to tweak?

```
<?php
    add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'woo_add_order_notes_to_email' );

    function woo_add_order_notes_to_email() {
        global $woocommerce, $post;
        $args = array(
            'post_id'   => $post->ID,
            'approve'   => 'approve',
            'type'    => 'order_note'
        );
        $notes = get_comments( $args );

        echo '<h2>' . __( 'Order Notes', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h2>';
        echo '<ul class="order_notes">';

        if ( $notes ) {
            foreach( $notes as $note ) {
              $note_classes = get_comment_meta( $note->comment_ID, 'is_customer_note', true ) ? array( 'customer-note', 'note' ) : array( 'note' );
              ?>
              <li rel="<?php echo absint( $note->comment_ID ) ; ?>" class="<?php echo implode( ' ', $note_classes ); ?>">
                <div class="note_content">
                  (<?php printf( __( 'added %s ago', 'woocommerce' ), human_time_diff( strtotime( $note->comment_date_gmt ), current_time( 'timestamp', 1 ) ) ); ?>) <?php echo wpautop( wptexturize( wp_kses_post( $note->comment_content ) ) ); ?>
                </div>
              </li>
              <?php
            }
        } else {
            echo '<li>' . __( 'There are no notes for this order yet.', 'woocommerce' ) . '</li>';
        }

        echo '</ul>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean *only* the last two instead of all?

Answer (score 0):

You can try use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

After the if and before the foreach

```
$notes = array_slice($notes, 0, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I will try that in a bit and let you know!